# Image not being drawn. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">

var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var cxt=c.getContext("2d");
var img=new Image();
img.src="Images/cloud_two.png";
cxt.drawImage(img,0,0);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to draw the image inside of a onload function, so after...

```
img.src="Images/cloud_two.png";
```

put

```
img.onload = function(){
    cxt.drawImage(img,0,0);
}
```

Hope this helps and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/alp82/PBFzu/

I replaced the URL to the image, so i guess your path is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the drawing inside `img.onload` as described here:

[MDC Canvas tutorial: Using images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images#Creating_an_image_from_scratch)